# if not break not working in python server

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a client server setup from a tutorial, but the server is stuck in the while loop below and i can't figure out why. 
I have searched through the questions on here and as far as I can see it should work.

I'm sure it will be something simple. I'm new to Python so any help would be appreciated.
Please know this is my first question so i hope it works ok.

I'm using python 3.5.2

```
# create a client thread
def clientthread(conn):
    # sending message to the client
    message = 'Welcome to the Server. Type something and hit Enter\n'
    conn.send(message.encode())  # send only takes a string

    while 1:
        # receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data.decode(): break
        reply = 'OK ' + data.decode()
        conn.sendall(reply.encode())

    # came out of loop
    conn.close()

# keep server up
while 1:

    # accept incomming connections
    conn, addr = soc.accept()

    # display client info
    print('Connected with' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1]))
    # start a new thread takes function name and a tupal
    start_new_thread(clientthread, (conn, ))

soc.close()
```

Comment: `break`s only exit the innermost loop. In other words, the `break` only closes the connection (the `while` loop you have in `clientthread`) - it does not kill the server (i.e. it does not exit the loop before `soc.accept()`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i know it only breaks the inner loop, but that is the issue, it doesn't ever break out of the inner loop no matter what i do. I thought that if i just pressed return the break should be activated but it doesn't, so i can never close the connection.

Comment: Figured out the issue, I was using telnet to test the server and it adds a \r\n to the end which the server see's as data so never shuts down.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue, I was using telnet to test the server and it adds a \r\n to the end which the server see's as data so never shuts down. Added code to check for this and works fine now